# Asciidoclet for JavaDoc using Maven

Tags: java, maven, intellij-14, asciidoctor

I'm working on writing documentation for my Java code using JavaDoc. I'm using IntelliJ as my IDE, and executing `javadoc -d javadoc src/* -author -version -private` as my command to generate HTML documentation from Java classes. So far, this has worked flawlessly.

However, I'm trying to use the AsciiDocs format to write my documentation in the Java classes, which I can do using [*AsciiDoclet*](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoclet). I'm using Maven, which I have never used before, to add the plugin for asciidoclet. Here's how that file looks:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Documentation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <doclet>org.asciidoctor.Asciidoclet</doclet>
                <docletArtifact>
                    <groupId>org.asciidoctor</groupId>
                    <artifactId>asciidoclet</artifactId>
                    <!--suppress UnresolvedMavenProperty -->
                    <version>${asciidoclet.version}</version>
                </docletArtifact>
                <overview>src/main/java/overview.adoc</overview>
                <additionalparam>
                    --base-dir ${project.basedir}
                    --attribute "name=${project.name}"
                    --attribute "version=${project.version}"
                    --attribute "title-link=http://example.com[${project.name} ${project.version}]"
                </additionalparam>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

When I click 'Compile' in the Maven window, i get the following error:

```
Source option 5 is no longer supported. Use 6 or later.
Target option 1.5 is no longer supported. Use 1.6 or later.
```

And a warning that might not be a big deal:

```
File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
```

Now, I don't know how to fix this issue, and I have looked for help but there is not that many resources/examples on how to do this. I'm also a bit confused on if I should still run `javadoc -d javadoc src/* -author -version -private`
once this plugin is working, or if I should run `asciidoctor --destination-dir=asciidoc src/*`.

Running the asciidoctor command did seem to understand what I was passing in (Java files instead of .adoc files), but the syntax didn't render correctly, probably due to the plugin issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your maven build and see if it makes a difference:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>17</maven.compiler.release>
  </properties>
```

Use '17' if your java version is 17. Change it accordingly to your own version.
See if this works and let us know.